# Getting exception java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'XXXX'

Tags: model, liferay, portlet, liferay-6, sqlexception

I have my custom portlet in liferay6 and I am getting exception while inserting long data in database as `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'XXXX' at row 1`

This is happening even when I have given following parameter in the `portlet-modal-hints`

```
<field name="advurl" type="String">
    <hint name="max-length">4000</hint>
</field>
```

This is the String in column which is throwing error: `http://www.coderanch.com/t/435635/java/java/Regular-expression-check-specific-special`

can anyone please tell me why this is still throwing an error?

#### Error stack

```
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.ExceptionTranslator.translate(ExceptionTranslator.java:30)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:122)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ClassLoaderSession.flush(ClassLoaderSession.java:218)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.BatchSessionImpl.update(BatchSessionImpl.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.BatchSessionUtil.update(BatchSessionUtil.java:50)
    at emenu.advertise.database.service.persistence.advertisePersistenceImpl.updateImpl(advertisePersistenceImpl.java:505)
    ... 178 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:119)
    ... 182 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'advlink' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1257)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:943)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 188 more
```

can anyone give me some suggestion?

Comment: Can you check if the database column has been updated after you **re-built** the service and **re-deployed** the portlet?

Comment: yes...its updated with the longtext datatype in mysql database

Comment: but i didnt redeployed it..let me try with redeploying the portlet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747079/getting-exception-java-sql-batchupdateexception-data-truncation-data-too-long#comment20637488_14747079) to answer to resolve this question :-)

You should rebuild the service after the change in the `portal-model-hints.xml` file.

And then you should re-deploy the plugin portlet to have the change take effect.

so please check if the database column has been updated after you have performed the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when the table (field length) which you have created using service.xml is different from what you are submitting.

You can try restricting your text-box or text area with a property maxlength="4000"
This wont allow you to post more than 4000 words.